# I'm trying to install composer and I get this error

Tags: composer-php

The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The program failed to run correctly. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. Make sure you have installed the appropriate Visual C++ Redistributable. I have Visual C++ Redistributable installed. I have even modified the php.ini file but still I can't install composer.

Comment: Can you share the exact command you executed?

Comment: That’s the error code I get.

Comment: That's why I've asked about the command you've executed

Comment: No command executed. I was installing from .exe